# Save a list of dataframes as a file in python

Tags: python, dataframe, save

Suppose that `list_dfs` is a list of many dataframes. What is the fastest way to save this list as a file on the storage device and read it again?

Answer (score 1):

pickle's protocol [version 5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/).
**Note that this reduces compatibility.**